# Using Regular expressions in java to extract contents of xml tag

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which is huge and a part of it contains as the following :

```
<df>asdffs</df><titletext xml:lang="eng" original="y">Dose intensity <inf>low</inf> in advanced cancer: Have we answered the question?</titletext><sdf>gfdgas</sdf>
```

I need to find if `<inf>` tag exists in the `<titletext>` tag.
I am writing it in Java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't use regex to parse xml. use an xml library instead

Comment: @gefei the OP did't want to parse `xml` using `regexp`. he want's to match some tags with pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using an XML parser ([SAX](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/SAXDemo.htm), since your document is supposedly large - it won't load all your document into memory at once but rather stream it through) and parsing it this way. You'll avoid all sort of edge cases which regular expression handlers can't handle (since XML isn't *regular*)

In your example above, you should likely maintain a stack of encountered XML elements, and track if `<inf>` is preceeded by `<titletext>`

Comment: Some example code should be nice ;-) OP has probably never worked with such a library so it's quite likely this question will be upvoted for it's correctness, but OP won't benefit from this since it's theoretical.